# Fazer transição "Fill from left" em background

Tags: html, css, css-transições

Preciso fazer uma transição *fill from left* no background de um botão.
Algo bem parecido como está em http://h5bp.github.io/Effeckt.css/dist/#0 (procurar o botão "fill from left").

Quero que quando eu passe o mouse em cima dele, ele preencha o background da esquerda para a direita. Minha sintaxe está assim:

```
  .BT{
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 330px;
    line-height: 30px;
    top: 350px;
    width: 110px;
}
```

E o Hover desse botão, que está errado, está assim:

```
.BT:hover{background-color:red;
transform:translate(-10%, 0px); 
transition:transform 500ms ease 0s;
}
```

O que acontece, é que ele está movimentando o botão, queria fazer um teste para movimentar internamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código que você colocou é para movimentar o botão. Caso queira movimentar o fundo você pode animar a posição dele: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KuB2N/))

```
.btn {
  background: #fff linear-gradient(90deg, #8f2 50%, #59f 50%);
  background-position: 0% center;
  background-size: 200%;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-position: 100% center;
}
```

Caso queira animar um elemento dentro do botão olhe esse exemplo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vU4YM/1/).

Comment: A sua dica funcionou 100%. Tenho apenas uma dúvida, vi que você usou CSS3, será que isso rola no IE8? :D

Comment: Ele só não vai ter a transição suave.

Comment: E já tinha esquecido: você tem que trocar o fundo por uma imagem estática.

Comment: Cara, tá nota 10, agora vou fazer uma pergunta muito idiota, como fazer ele transicionar da esquerda para a direita? o contrário do que está agora?

Comment: Mude as background-position.

Comment: Fiz alterações no "background-position" e não obtive sucesso. =/

Comment: Troque o valor `background-position` entre as regras com e sem `:hover`.

Comment: Consegui, muito obrigado novamente! :D

.btn {
  background: #fff linear-gradient(90deg, #8f2 50%, #59f 50%);
  background-position: 100% center;
  background-size: 200%;
  transition: background-position 1s;
  text-align: center; padding: 1em;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-position: 0% center;
}